# Import Data in LDAP server

Tags: ldap

I have to create a LDAP server which gets user information from application (say APP01) and send to another application (say APP2). I have created a OpenLDAP server and installed JXplorer and created some users(test data) using JXplorer.

APP02 has functionality to connect to OpenLDAP server and connection is successful and getting my test data in APP02.

My problem is get data (import data) from APP01 automatically. Can a LDAP server import DATA?

I m getting data from APP01 in form of CSv file, do I need to build a >net application to send to my OpenLDAP server or OpenLDAP server has functionality to import data..

Comment: can u put some line breaks in your question?

Comment: yeah i have done that.. sorry for unreadable typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The LDAP client can `import` data into the server - this operation replaces the existing database with the contents of a file containing LDIF
- The LDAP client can add data to the server database from a file containing LDIF `change records` using the `ldapmodify` or `ldapadd` tool. This operation does not change the existing database, rather it adds data or changes existing data.
- A commercial synchronization device can be deployed to synchronize data from a data source to a destination, the destination being the OpenLDAP server.

Comment: thanks for your reply..This is clear that throu LDIF file we can replace or Modify the LDAP server databse but my question is can we automate the process? or everytime we have to run the ldapadd , ladpmodify commandin command prompt???

Comment: This is clear that throu LDIF file we can replace or Modify the LDAP server databse but my question is can we automate the process?

Comment: i figured out.. the following two articles are very helpful and self explanatory    http://soswin-techbits.blogspot.nl/2011/10/installing-openldap-on-windows-7.html                                      http://kukusan-network.blogspot.nl/2012/01/how-to-setting-ldap-openldap-in-windows.html